# Conditionally including leading country code in phone number in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using [ngMask](https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask) in Angular for a phone number input. I'd like to include the leading 1 when a user includes it in the phone number and exclude it when the user doesn't include it. So `12125551212` will look like `1(212)555-1212` and `2125551212` will look like `(212)555-1212`

The code below only works when the user includes the leading 1. Here's the code for the mask (the `*?`s are to allow for extensions, etc.):

```
<input type="phone" id="phone" name="phone" ng-model="contactForm.contact.phone" 
validate="false" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="25" placeholder="(000) 000-0000" 
mask="1?(999) 999-9999 *?*?*?*?*?*?*?*?*?" class="form-control" required />
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with ngMask, or will I need to use a custom directive?

Comment: You can use an alternative mask based on updates for model: mask="getMask()"

Comment: @Joaozito Polo Would you mind elaborating a little bit on how the controller would determine which mask to use?

Comment: I think about a function to change mask when the input starts with "(1". please look at jsbin: http://jsbin.com/macama/edit?html,js,output . But ngMask doesn't consider the new mask.

Comment: @Joaozito Polo That example didn't work for me. 12125551212 looks like this in that example: `(121)255-5121`. Should be `1(212)555-1212`

Comment: Yes, I know. ngMask doesn't evaluate again the function mask... But the point is: maybe ngMask doesn't help you. I had used this jquery plugin: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask for input phone number, with a directive, because were I live the mask varies for some states. And my directive take the control of mask, and reapply the mask when the number of digits varies. jquery.inputmask plugin allows this. If you need further, I can to create a jsbin with my directive.

Comment: @Joaozito Polo Thanks. I'll take a look at that. But was hoping to get a solution that uses Angular without jQuery.